# PHP preg_match starting from end of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to capture a string pattern but starting from the end of the string.

If I have a string like:

```
"Hi, I saw you on tv yesterday. On Mon 4 P.M Alice wrote:"
```

A regular `preg_match` that captures everything between word `"on"` and word `"wrote:"` will capture `"on tv yesterday. On Mon 4 P.M Alice wrote:"`. I want to capture `"On Mon 4 P.M Alice wrote:"`.

I can't solve it with `preg_match_all` as it will just match the first one.

My pattern:

```
/(<div>|<br>|<br \/>|<br\/>)\s*on\s(.*)wrote:/i
```

I also tried to solve it with `strrpos` but it doesn't respect spaces.

Thanks,
       Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex for last match in your input for `preg_match`:

```
/\bon\b(?:(?!\bon\b).)*?\bwrote\b/i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yA7pP6/3)

`(?:(?!\bon\b).)*?` is negative lookahead based regex that will match text between `on` and `wrote` when `on` doesn't appear between them thus **making sure to match last match** in input.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be to use these nice functions I found [here](http://php.net/substr). Personally I use it quite often, and it never let me down.

```
<?php    
function strrevpos($instr, $needle)
    {
        $rev_pos = strpos (strrev($instr), strrev($needle));
        if ($rev_pos===false) return false;
        else return strlen($instr) - $rev_pos - strlen($needle);
    };
     function before ($this, $inthat)
        {
            return substr($inthat, 0, strpos($inthat, $this));
        };
     function between ($this, $that, $inthat)
        {
            return before ($that, after($this, $inthat));
        };
?>
```

You can then just easily do:

```
$string = 'Hi, I saw you on tv yesterday. On Mon 4 P.M Alice wrote:"';
$result = between ('On', 'wrote:', $string);
echo $result; //should echo "Mon 4 P.M Alice"
```